# how to pass value with # in url to php

Tags: php, html

I send value to php file. It contains `#` and some special characters.

How can I get actual value.

```
window.location.href = "somepage.php?w1=" data-target="#myModal1" ;
```

It returns value in php
 `data-target="!`

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding?

Comment: I'm confused.... wouldn't it be better to use `header()` in PHP, rather than Javascript? Does `w1` equal a certain value? Can you post your whole code, rather than just a snippet?

Comment: No because. i want original value what can i pass value.

Comment: Can you post your whole code, rather than just a snippet?

Comment: i send the value to php from html.how i can do it.                                  <img class="imageclass" src="images/hotspot.png" width="30px" height="30px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" style="top:345px; left:393px; z-index: 1; position: absolute;">

Comment: If you encode the value, you can decode it using your PHP script, which will yield the original value? http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: If you are talking about the URL fragment `#something`, you can not get this on the server.  It is client side only.

Comment: ...unless you encode the `#` as a special character ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before passing a variable using the url first add a '?' to the end of the normal url

**www.htmlexample.org/phpexample.php?**

after the ? add the name of the variable

**www.htmlexample.org/phpexample.php?varName**

put an "=" then add the value assigned to the variable name

**www.htmlexample.org/phpexample.php?varName=value**

to pass more then one variable repeat above but only have **'?'** before the first one and a **'&'** in between each new variable

To get the variable values from the url use the **$_GET method**

Example

```
www.htmlexample.org/phpexample.php?varName=value&othervarName=othervalue
```

for example to get the value of the variable varName use

```
$_GET["varName"]
```

use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) the same as any other method